# Why is Geany IDE NOT catching an error? EXIT_SUCCESS; needs correct header file, c++

Tags: c++

On both windows and linux I am using Geany IDE and writing a c++ program. For some reason right now it is not catching an error on either linux/windows. I am using EXIT_SUCCESS and need to have the header file , right? also using copy function and it requires ? It only stops when I exclude  and  I discovered this because in my code I left it out by accident but it compiled, built and ran just fine.

It catches it when I use just G++, I'm not sure what is going on, could it be some setting I have in Geany?

Here is the code I'm working with

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
//~ #include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    int xSize = 10;
    int ySize = 50;
    int xData[xSize];
    int yData[ySize];

    for(int i = 0; i < xSize; ++i) {
        xData[i] = i;
        std::cout << " First X Array value: "<< xData[i] << " " << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i = ySize; i >= 0; --i) {
        yData[i] = i;
        std::cout << " First Y Array value: "<< yData[i] << " " << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::copy(xData, xData+6,yData+42);

    std::cout << "The copy function added it's first 6 values to the yData array starting at Y's 42nd array position" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 42; i < ySize; ++i) {
        std::cout << "First array value of Y is now: " << yData[i] << std::endl;
    }
    assert(yData[42]==0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Some header files might (directly or indirectly) include other header files. It's implementation details that you can't rely on. Always include the header files you require.

Comment: Simply add following  `#ifndef EXIT_SUCCESS #define EXIT_SUCCESS 0 #endif #ifndef EXIT_FAILURE #define EXIT_FAILURE -1 #endif` before the  `int main()`